# Why is Chrome 10 times faster at uploading files to Google Drive than Firefox?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, speed, upload

I've noticed than Chrome is around 10 times faster at uploading files to Google Drive than Firefox. What could explain that? I use Windows 10.

[image: r]

Comment: What type of performance gap do you have when your not trying to upload the files at the same time?

Comment: @Ramhound same.

Comment: Could be that, since Google owns Chrome browser, they allow faster upload from it to Google Drive. You could test,  by making the Firefox browser appear as Chrome with an add-on, such as User-Agent Switcher and Manager .